# How do i return to the start of the code in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, return

I want to make a program that will loop itself.
I have tried using return but it doesnt work.
How do i return to the start of the code in a batch file ?
Thank you.

Comment: take a look at `goto /? `and `call /?`

Answer (score 1):

If the `shift` keyword has not been used then this will relaunch the same batch file:

```
%0
```

Another way is to use this style of code:

```
@echo off
:loop
   echo starting %0
   rem more code here
goto :loop
```

Comment: @djangofan I am under the impression that you can edit other peoples answers to correct a simple flaw, not to change the answer or add extra information.  Use a comment to do that or add your own answer.